# kubernetes python client get value of a specific annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes

I'm trying to get the value of a node annotation with kubernetes python client.

This code print all the annotations for nodes with etcd nodes :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from kubernetes import client, config

def main():
    config.load_kube_config("./backup_kubeconfig_prod")
    label_selector = 'node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd'

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing nodes with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_node(watch=False, label_selector=label_selector)

    for i in ret.items:
      print(i.metadata.annotations)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output example :

```
{'flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager': 'true', 'flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type': 'vxlan', 'flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data': '{"VtepMAC":"96:70:f6:ab:4f:30"}', 'rke.cattle.io/internal-ip': '1.2.3.4', 'volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach': 'true', 'flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip': '1.2.3.4', 'rke.cattle.io/external-ip': '1.2.3.4', 'node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl': '0'}
```

How can I print the value of `flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip` for example ?

Comment: What is the type of `i.metadata.annotations`? Can you print it along the values using `print(type(i.metadata.annotations))`?

Comment: it's `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: Can you check the output of `print(i.metadata.annotations["flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip"])` ?

Comment: it works yes ! Could you put the solution in comment as I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data in `i.metadata.annotations` are dictionary type.

You can print the value of the key `flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip` using:

```
print(i.metadata.annotations["flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip"])
```

Answer (score 0):

below works:

`print("Annontation: {}".format(i.metadata.annotations['flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip']))`

labels and annotations are dictionary, on which we can not iterate as items. So we have to do get values for labels and annotation in this way.